# How to get a single valid email address out of 20 obfuscated email addresses using Python

Tags: python, email, decode, deobfuscation

I would like to decode the email.
Input:

```
obfuscated_email_addresses_raw = '''hknrnajuw@moulcgs.net, oituugim@jdcq.net, woecfsgyu@ynjbghrj.edu, yabygip@qmqmulu.edu, ysio@ydok.org, gbpum@bccds.edu, onmfy@uomiuju.org, hfujlo@rorthqgn.gov, nkhpanbya@tsngmfe.net, michael@hmblawoffice.com, pojesgpu@ypkqgti.net, fatuqwh@tmaqnggr.org, wqlpij@jeyfe.gov, abww@wjy.gov, unhdj@mroi.com, nhaw@qoh.com, iljqin@cehh.edu, mdsidnsok@ilnf.gov, jpofhqa@qyigalj.org, qwwlpfwe@ldrph.org'''

list_of_obfuscated_email_addresses = [i.strip() for i in w.split(',')]
print(len(list_of_obfuscated_email_addresses))
```

From above code, we can see there is only one email address which turns out to be valid, that is michael@hmblawoffice.com.

Is there any way to get only one valid email out of obfuscated email using Python?

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
michael@hmblawoffice.com

Thanks ahead!

Comment: What are the criteria for validity?

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb for your question. Actually, I am not sure what would be the validation criteria, but as you could see from `obfuscated_email_addresses_raw`  that there are 19 emails those are somehow encoded using some kind of method which I don't know, I  wish if I could identify those emails encoded, so that would allow to deduct those encoded/obfuscated emails , get the valid email address. In another word, I wish to have a way identify which ones are encoded/ obfuscated. Does this make sense? I've a CSV file containing around 200K rows, each row contains such 20 email addresses.

Comment: make a DNS request to distinguish existing domains from fake

Comment: Hi @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks for your response in this regard. I've had a thought about it, will look into it. However, I was just curious if there was any other way around to decode these kinds of obscured email addresses and extract the original one. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's impossible to deduce the decoding method from a single line from your big file.